# Why isn't SQL ANSI-92 standard better adopted over ANSI-89?

Tags: sql, join, ansi-sql, ansi-92

At every company I have worked at, I have found that people are still writing their SQL queries in the ANSI-89 standard:

```
select a.id, b.id, b.address_1
from person a, address b
where a.id = b.id
```

rather than the ANSI-92 standard:

```
select a.id, b.id, b.address_1
from person a
inner join address b
on a.id = b.id
```

For an extremely simple query like this, there's not a big difference in readability, but for large queries I find that having my join criteria grouped in with listing out the table makes it much easier to see where I might have issues in my join, and let's me keep all my filtering in my WHERE clause.  Not to mention that I feel that outer joins are much intuitive than the (+) syntax in Oracle.

As I try to evangelize ANSI-92 to people, are there any concrete performance benefits in using ANSI-92 over ANSI-89?  I would try it on my own, but the Oracle setups we have here don't allow us to use EXPLAIN PLAN - wouldn't want people to try to optimize their code, would ya?

Comment: One primary advantage of the SQL-92 join notation is that there is a standard and relatively sane way of writing LEFT OUTER JOIN and variants.  Each DBMS had its own variant syntax (usually bad; actually, I think, without exception the notations were bad) and often with slightly different semantics.  SQL-92 fixed that, and the new notation is worth using on those grounds alone.  I think it is clearer anyway, once you're used to it.  It takes a little getting used to, but it is not hard, and once converted, there's no going back.

Comment: semantics, shemantics, anti-shemantics!

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party here, but no-one seems to have pointed out that Oracle themselves [recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Joins.htm#SQLRF52354)

Comment: I've added a new answer that is very much more up to date and straightforward, with clarity over other misconceptions in the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47720615/124486

Comment: 92 joins are probably adopted much better by now, seeing as your question is from 2008. I had never heard the terms "ANSI 92 JOIN" or "ANSI 89 JOIN", and I thought that an "ANSI-JOIN" was the older 89 syntax. I learned 92 joins first, but after reading that postgres often converts joins to the 89 form under the hood, and that they don't force the query planner into a certain join order as much, I started using them more. I now like the 89 syntax more because I've experienced better performance and the syntax is much more terse.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

According to "SQL Performance Tuning" by Peter Gulutzan and Trudy Pelzer, of the six or eight RDBMS brands they tested, there was no difference in optimization or performance of SQL-89 versus SQL-92 style joins.  One can assume that most RDBMS engines transform the syntax into an internal representation before optimizing or executing the query, so the human-readable syntax makes no difference.

I also try to evangelize the SQL-92 syntax.  Sixteen years after it was approved, it's about time people start using it!  And all brands of SQL database now support it, so there's no reason to continue to use the nonstandard `(+)` Oracle syntax or `*=` Microsoft/Sybase syntax.

As for why it's so hard to break the developer community of the SQL-89 habit, I can only assume that there's a large "base of the pyramid" of programmers who code by copy & paste, using ancient examples from books, magazine articles, or another code base, and these people don't learn new syntax abstractly.  Some people pattern-match, and some people learn by rote.

I am gradually seeing people using SQL-92 syntax more frequently than I used to, though.  I've been answering SQL questions online since 1994.

Comment: I totally agree.  I work with many SQL coders who learnt their SQL 15 years ago or more (as I did myself) and who know nothing of any innovation since they first started.  They also lack any interest in finding out.

Comment: Agree, but add that there are well-documented scenarios where the old ANSI-89 Join syntax produces incorrect results... specifically outer Joins when there are conditional filtering predicates on non-Join related columns from the "outer" side of the join.

Comment: I've noticed massive performance gains by using the ANSI-92 code over the ANSI-89 code on MSSQL (2k and 2k5) here at work.  I think MSSQL is actually stupid enough to do a Cartesian join and then filter the results with the where clause... or maybe it just somehow prevents it from using the index?

Comment: I don't know specific internals of MS SQL, but that's good anecdotal evidence that SQL-92 syntax is worthwhile.  Works for me!

Comment: Massive? Please post your work. My best bet is that it's not an apples to apples comparison, but don't respond with "oh yes it is" Just respond with a test case we can reproduce, version, patch level etc.

Comment: Well, I already want SQL-92 syntax to be used.  So if it's true that it does no harm and may improve performance, do we need to know by how much?

Comment: Besides, "anecdotal" evidence is not a scientific measure anyway.  It is always taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: I believe basing decision or formulating persuasions on lies, no matter how harmless or well intentioned is bad practice. People should expect to show their work. I have. I've been asked to prove answers and spent quite some time to do so.

Comment: Hey, just for kicks look at the patch notes for 10.2.0.4. You'll see a TON of fixes to ANSI SQL. So there is a performance difference. Oracle seems to have missed something in the parser.

Comment: 2022 and it's stilll happening.. I found this post because we're still arguing about which standard to follow

Answer (score 17):

Well the ANSI092 standard includes some pretty heinous syntax. [Natural Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Natural_join) are one and the USING Clause is another. IMHO, the addition of a column to a table shouldn't break code but a NATURAL JOIN breaks in a most egregious fashion. The "best" way to break is by compilation error. For example if you SELECT * somewhere, the addition of a column **could** fail to compile. The next best way to fail would be a run time error. It's worse because your users may see it, but it still gives you a nice warning that you've broken something. If you use ANSI92 and write queries with NATURAL joins, it won't break at compile time and it won't break at run time, the query will just suddenly start producing wrong results. These types of bugs are insidious. Reports go wrong, potentially financial disclosure are incorrect.

For those unfamiliar with NATURAL Joins. They join two tables on every column name that exists in both tables. Which is really cool when you have a 4 column key and you're sick of typing it. The problem comes in when Table1 has a pre-existing column named DESCRIPTION and you add a new column to Table2 named, oh I don't know, something innocuous like, mmm, DESCRIPTION and now you're joining the two tables on a VARCHAR2(1000) field that is free form.

The USING clause can lead to total ambiguity in addition to the problem described above. In another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228424/111424), someone showed this ANSI-92 SQL and asked for help reading it.

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM companies AS c 
JOIN users AS u USING(companyid) 
JOIN jobs AS j USING(userid) 
JOIN useraccounts AS us USING(userid) 
WHERE j.jobid = 123
```

This is completely ambiguous. I put a UserID column in both Companies and user tables and there's no complaint. What if the UserID column in companies is the ID of the last person to modify that row?

**I'm serious, Can anyone explain why such ambiguity was necessary? Why is it built straight into the standard?**

I think Bill is correct that there is a large base of developer who copy/paste there way through coding. In fact, I can admit that I'm kind of one when it comes to ANSI-92. Every example I ever saw showed multiple joins being nested in parentheses. Honesty, that makes picking out the tables in the sql difficult at best. But then an SQL92 evangilist explained that would actually force a join order. JESUS... all those Copy pasters I've seen are now actually forcing a join order - a job that's 95% of the time better left to optimizers *especially* a copy/paster.

Tomalak got it right when he said,

> people don't switch to new syntax just
>   because it is there

It has to give me something and I don't see an upside. And if there is an upside, the negatives are an albatross too big to be ignored.

Comment: I tend to use ON because it's less ambiguous than USING or NATURAL JOIN.  As for parentheses, people who learn "SQL" on Microsoft Access will use that as Access whines if you omit them. (The quotes around SQL should be finger quotes.)

Comment: *Cough* What's a USING clause? ;-) I come from the SQL server fraction, so this is not really on my radar. As R. Bemrose said, there is the ON clause, working just fine, never leaving me with a join I could not express syntactically. No need to adapt my DB design to query syntax to save some typing.

Comment: RB & T, yes that's fine but they are in the standard. Oh the humanity, why?

Comment: I never use NATURAL JOIN for the reasons you mention.  If you use USING in an ambiguous way, the RDBMS should give you an error.  MySQL does, for example.  Compile-time failure is not possible when programmer use dynamic SQL.

Comment: If you don't know your data well enough to use NATURAL JOIN or USING when appropriate, you probably shouldn't be writing SQL for it.  -1 for ignorance.

Comment: IMHO, natural joins fall into the same bag as `SELECT *` (then finding out the client relies on field order)- It just feels a little sloppy

Comment: The problem you describe with natural joins is a problem with your database design - not one with the standard. you should be aware of your data, and have established standards for column names.

Comment: The same can be said of your USING ambiguity example. The problem is that you don't have standard naming conventions for your columns. If you keep a column that specifies who made a change, that column should have a unique, recognizable name which NOT used for any other purpose. Your forced order argument is perfectly valid, however.

Comment: I believe a NATRUAL JOIN has it's place.  And that is only when any given column name can only mean one thing.  if the two table have a user id, and one is the user id of the last change, and the other is the user id of created by field, then they are not NATURAL JOIN columns, because they mean different things, even if they relate to a user in the user table. Careful naming of columns is critical in NATURAL JOINS.  This type of join works best in an OODB rather than a more traditional RDB.

Comment: How is it ambiguous, do you even know what that means? You're explicitly joining where both sides is a column name. If that column name doesn't exist, the join fails. It's not at all ambiguous.

Comment: Re [the point of natural join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35034568/3404097).

Answer (score 14):

A few reasons come to mind:

- people do it out of habit
- people are lazy and prefer the "old style" joins because they involve less typing
- beginners often have their problems wrapping their heads around the SQL-92 join syntax
- people don't switch to new syntax just because it is there
- people are unaware of the benefits the new (if you want  to call it that) syntax has, primarily that it enables you to filter a table *before* you do an outer join, and not after it when all you have is the WHERE clause.

For my part, I do all my joins in the SQL-92 syntax, and I convert code where I can. It's the cleaner, more readable and powerful way to do it. But it's hard to convince someone to use the new style, when they think it hurts them in terms of more typing work while not changing the query result.

Comment: For many people, looking at SQL at all hurts them.  Changing any working code carries a risk for introducing a bug, especially when the coder is averting his eyes.  :-)

Comment: Hm... to me even looking at complex regular expressions is no hurt at all. SQL can't harm me. ;-)

Comment: "Beginners often have problems... " Well THAT'S a selling point

Comment: For some reason I'm not sure if that was a "pro" or a "contra" comment... Maybe my irony detector is broken.

Answer (score 11):

In response to the NATURAL JOIN and USING post above.

WHY would you ever see the need to use these - they weren't available in ANSI-89 and were added for ANSI-92 as what I can only see as a shortcut.

I would never leave a join to chance and would always specify the table/alias and id.

For me, the only way to go is ANSI-92. It is more verbose and the syntax isn't liked by ANSI-89 followers but it neatly separates your JOINS from your FILTERING.

Comment: I don't see NATURAL JOINs as a shortcut, but a Segway into Object Oriented DB programming within a Relational DB.

Comment: Natural joins are really obscure and error prone. Avoid them and sleep well.

Answer (score 5):

First let me say that in SQL Server the outer join syntax (*=) does not give correct results all the time. There are times when it interprets that as a cross join and not an outer join. So right there is a good reason to stop using it. And that outer join syntax is a deprecated feature and will not be in the next version of SQL Server after  SQL Server 2008. You'll still be able to do the inner joins but why on earth would anyone want to? They are unclear and much much harder to maintain. You don't easily know what is part of the join and what is really just the where clause.

One reason why I believe you should not use the old syntax is that understanding joins and what they do and do not do is a critical step for anyone who will write SQL code. You should not write any SQL code without understanding joins thoroughly. If you understand them well, you will probably come to the conclusion that the ANSI-92 syntax is clearer and easier to maintain. I've never met a SQL expert who didn't use the ANSI-92 syntax in preference to the old syntax.

Most people who I have met or dealt with who use the old code, truly don't understand joins and thus get into trouble when querying the database. This is my personal experience so I'm not saying it is always true. But as a data specialist, I've had to fix too much of this junk through the years not to believe it.

Comment: Glad to meet you. Happy to be your first.

Answer (score 4):

I was taught ANSI-89 in school and worked in industry for a few years. Then I left the fabulous world of DBMS for 8 years.  But then I came back and this new ANSI 92 stuff was being taught.  I have learned the Join On syntax and now I actually teach SQL and I recommend the new JOIN ON syntax.

But the downside that I see is correlated subqueries don't seem to make sense in the light of ANSI 92 joins. When join information was included in the WHERE and correlated subqueries are "joined" in the WHERE all seemed right and consistent.  In ANSI 92 table join criteria is not in the WHERE and subquery  "join" is, the syntax seems inconsistent.  On the other hand, trying to "fix" this inconsistency would probably just make it worse.

Comment: On the other hand, you p[robaly shoudl not be writing correlated subqueries at all as they are perrformance hogs. They are like putting a cursor into your query. Ugh.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the answer for sure.. this is a religous war (albiet of a lesser degree than Mac-Pc or others)

A guess is that until fairly recently, Oracle, (and maybe other vendors as well) did not adopt the ANSI-92 standard (I think it was in Oracle v9, or thereabouts) and so, for DBAs/Db Developers working at companies which were still using these versions, (or wanted code to be portable across servers that might be using these versions, they had to stick to the old standard...

It's a shame really, because the new join syntax is much more readable, and the old syntax generates wrong (incorrect) results in several well-documented scenarios.

- Specifically, outer Joins when there
  are conditional filtering predicates
  on non-Join related columns from the
  table on the "outer" side of the
  join.

Comment: Yes, Oracle 9i; released in 2001.  A little late to the party!

Comment: MS SQL added `INNER JOIN` in 1995, though `LEFT JOIN` not until 1996.  MySQL has supported it at least since 3.23, released in 1999; PostgreSQL at least since 7.2, released in 2002.  Some casual Googling gives me no answer for Teradata.

Comment: Yes, that was the condemnation which proved the superiority of Oracle in 1991: database systems like MS access which used the "Left" and "Right" syntax weren't ANSI standard SQL.  Posting SQL like that was an opportunity for other people to sneer at you.  Kind of like twitter and facebook now.

Answer (score 3):

I had a query that was originally written for SQL Server 6.5, which did not support the SQL 92 join syntax, i.e.

```
select foo.baz
from foo
  left outer join bar
  on foo.a = bar.a
```

was instead written as

```
select foo.baz
from foo, bar
where foo.a *= bar.a
```

The query had been around for a while, and the relevant data had accumulated to make the query run too slow, abut 90 seconds to complete. By the time this problem arose, we had upgraded to SQL Server 7.

After mucking about with indexes and other Easter-egging, I changed the join syntax to be SQL 92 compliant. The query time dropped to 3 seconds.

There's a good reason to switch.

Reposted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700868/what-was-your-coolest-sql-optimization-on-a-slow-performing-query).

Answer (score 2):

Inertia and practicality.

ANSI-92 SQL is like touch-typing. In some theoretical way it might make everything better someday, but I can type much faster looking at the keys with four fingers now. I would need to go backwards in order to go forwards, with no guarantee that there would ever be a pay-off.

Writing SQL is about 10% of my job. If I need ANSI-92 SQL to solve a problem that ANSI-89 SQL can't solve then I'll use it. (I use it in Access, in fact.) If using it all the time would help me solve my existing problems much faster, I'd spend the time to assimilate it. But I can whip out ANSI-89 SQL without ever thinking about the syntax. I get paid to solve problems--thinking about SQL syntax is a waste of my time and of my employer's money.

Someday, young Grasshopper, you'll be defending your use of ANSI-92 SQL syntax against young people whining that you should be using SQL3 (or whatever). And then you'll understand. :-)

Comment: The approach described here sounds a LOT like the "fix it when it breaks" school of thought, eschewing the idea of preventative maintenance. You get paid to solve problems, yes, but you also get paid to provide more value to your company. ANSI-89 in your case provides greater value in the short term, but in the long run not investing time in ANSI-92 will be the more expensive option.

Comment: Sticking to what you've always done comes with a cost for the poor guy that has to maintain your code when you're gone.  That doesn't mean you should switch to the flavor of the month, but adopting best practices will almost always pay off in maintainability.

Comment: I won't switch to Excel (where you can do anything in three clicks of the mouse or less), because I have memorized the thousands of Lotus 123 commands that I need and I'm comfortable using them! 
Hah!

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few points comparing SQL-89, and SQL-92 and clearing up some misconceptions in other answers.

1. `NATURAL JOINS` are a horrible idea. They're implicit and they require meta-information about the table. Nothing about SQL-92 requires their use so simply **ignore them**. They're not relevant to this discussion.
2. `USING` is a great idea, it has two effects:

   1. It produces only one column on the result set from an equijoin.
   2. It's enforces a sound and sane convention. In SQL-89 you had people writing the column `id` on both tables. After you join the tables, this becomes and ambiguous and it requires explicit aliasing. Further, the `id`s on the join almost certainly had different data. If you join person to company, you now have to alias one `id` to `person_id`, and one `id` to `company_id`, without which the join would produce two ambiguous columns. Using a globally-unique identifier for the table's surrogate key is the convention the standard rewards with `USING`.
3. The SQL-89 syntax is an implicit `CROSS JOIN`. A `CROSS JOIN` doesn't reduce the set, it implicitly grows it. `FROM T1,T2` is the same as `FROM T1 CROSS JOIN T2`, that produces a Cartesian join which is usually not what you want. Having the selectivity to reduce that removed to a distant `WHERE` conditional means that you're more likely to make mistakes during design.
4. SQL-89 `,` and SQL-92 explicit `JOIN`s have different precedence. `JOIN` has a higher precedence. Even worse, [some databases like MySQL got this wrong for a very long time.](https://pento.net/2009/04/03/join-and-comma-precedence/). So mixing the two styles is a bad idea, and the far more popular style today is the SQL-92 style.

Comment: 1) If you study the relational model, you will appreciate that, no only is natural join a great idea, it is the only kind of join you need. 2) See 1 i.e. not needed. 3) Regardless of syntax (and *both* are SQL-92 syntax), the relational operator is product (multiply) i.e. not really a join (Cartesian join' isn't even a thing). 4. See 1 i.e. not needed.

Comment: One point to note, is that natural joins are still useful when direct control of the columns exist within the query. Most notably, when joining two subqueries.

It is of course just syntactic sugar at that point, but it useful for improving the "signal to noise" ratio in a query.

Comment: You got my vote when you said "NATURAL JOINS are a horrible idea". Yes, they were poorly designed, since they assume there's at most one FK between each pair of tables. Real world databases don't follow that assumption and I think natural joins should be removed from SQL, the same way as the notorious `UNION JOIN` was removed in SQL-2003. I bet no one remember those anymore (except if you use HyperSQL, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I can answer from the point of view of an average developer, knowing just enough SQL to understand both syntaxes, but still googling the exact syntax of insert each time I need it... :-P (I don't do SQL all day, just fixing some problems from time to time.)

Well, actually, I find the first form more intuitive, making no apparent hierarchy between the two tables. The fact I learned SQL with possibly old books, showing the first form, probably doesn't help... ;-)
And the first reference I find on a *sql select* search in Google (which returns mostly French answers for me...) first shows the older form (then explain the second one).

Just giving some hints on the "why" question... ^_^ I should read a good, modern book (DB agnostic) on the topic. If somebody has suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for all schools but at my university when we were doing the SQL module of our course, they didn't teach ANSI-92, they taught ANSI-89 - on an old VAX system at that!  I wasn't exposed to ANSI-92 until I started digging around in Access having built some queries using the query designer and then digging into the SQL code.  Realising I had no idea how it was completing the joins, or the implications of the syntax I started digging deeper so I could understand it.

Given that the available documentation isn't exactly intuitive in a lot of cases, and that people tend to stick to what they know and in many cases don't strive to learn any more than they need in order to get their job done, it's easy to see why adoption is taking so long.

Of course, there are those technical evangelists that like to tinker and understand and it tends to be those types that adopt the "newer" principles and try to convert the rest.

Oddly, it seems to me that a lot of programmers come out of school and stop advancing; thinking that because this is what they were taught, this is how it's done.  It's not until you take off your blinkers that you realise that school was only meant to teach you the basics and give you enough understanding to learn the rest yourself and that really you barely scratched the surface of what there is to know; now it's your job to continue that path.

Of course, that's just my opinion based on my experience.

Comment: It's not just programmers.  In many fields, it's hard to convince people to retrain once they're established in their career.  There are exceptional individuals, of course, I assume in the same proportion in every field.

Comment: It's hard to convince someone to switch away from something successful, to something different that offers no benefit. Our .net side of the house has changed from 1.0 to 3.5 and each step in between with ZERO cajoling. Each new version was better. Can't say the same here.

Answer (score 1):

1) Standard way to write OUTER JOIN, versus *= or (+)=

2) NATURAL JOIN

3) Depend in the database engine, ANSI-92 trends to be more optimal.

4) Manual optimization :

Let's say that we have the next syntax (ANSI-89):

```
(1)select * from TABLE_OFFICES to,BIG_TABLE_USERS btu
where to.iduser=tbu.iduser and to.idoffice=1
```

It could be written as:

```
(2)select * from TABLE_OFFICES to
inner join BIG_TABLE_USERS btu on to.iduser=tbu.iduser
where to.idoffice=1
```

But also as :

```
(3)select * from TABLE_OFFICES to
inner join BIG_TABLE_USERS btu on to.iduser=tbu.iduser and to.idoffice=1
```

All of them (1),(2),(3) return the same result, however they are optimized differently, it depends in the database engine but most of them do :

- (1) its up to the database engine decide the optimization.
- (2) it joins both tables then do the filter per office.
- (3) it filters the BIG_TABLE_USERS using the idoffice then join both tables.

5) Longer queries are less messy.

Answer (score 1):

Reasons people use ANSI-89 from my practical experience with old and young programmers and trainees and fresh graduates:

- They learn SQL from existing code they see (rather than books) and learn ANSI-89 from code
- ANSI-89 because is less typing
- They do not think about it and use one or other style and do not even know which of both is considered new or old and do not care either
- The idea that code is also a communication to the next programmer coming along maintaining the code does not exist. They think they talk to the computer and the computer does not care.
- The art of "clean coding" is unknown
- Knowledge of programming language and SQL specifically is so poor that they copy and paste together what they find elsewhere
- Personal preference

I personally prefer ANSI-92 and change every query I see in ANSI-89 syntax sometimes only to better understand the SQL Statement at hand. But I realized that the majority of people I work with are not skilled enough to write joins over many tables. They code as good as they can and use what they memorized the first time they encountered a SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not implement ANSI-92 at all well. I've had several problems, not least because the data tables in Oracle Apps are so very well endowed with columns. If the number of columns in your joins exceeds about 1050 columns (which is very easy to do in Apps), then you will get this spurious error which makes absolutely no logical sense:

```
ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from a join view without a key-preserved table.
```

Re-writing the query to use old style join syntax makes the issue disappear, which seems to point the finger of blame squarely at the implementation of ANSI-92 joins.

Until I encountered this problem, I was a steadfast promoter of ASNI-92, because of the benefits in reducing the chance of an accidental cross join, which is far too easy to do with old-style syntax.

Now, however, I find it much more difficult to insist on it. They point to Oracle's bad implementation and say "We'll do it our way, thanks."

Comment: It may be easy to do a Cross Join, it's also something that doesn't happen spontaneously and it's certainly not ambiguous. Any decent SQL developer could spot it. But USING and NATURAL JOIN are temptresses which call out to you and smash your little boat on the rocks of anguish and misery.

Comment: My point was, it's easier to successfully create an accidental cross join by missing off the where clause that joins two tables together. A cross join has to be deliberate in ANSI-92. But I do agree that NATURAL JOIN is an abomination. :)

Comment: I understood your point. But it doesn't just happen out of the blue. As you debug your query you notice the problem and fix it. If you use natural join, with no changes -at all- to the query itself, it can change because of a table change.

Answer (score -3):

A new SQL standard inherits everything from the previous standard, a.k.a. 'the shackles of compatibility'. So the 'old' / 'comma-separated' / 'unqualified' join style is perfectly valid SQL-92 sytax.

Now, I argue that SQL-92's `NATURAL JOIN` is the only join you need. For example, I argue it is superior to `inner join` because it does not generate duplicate columns - no more range variables in `SELECT` clauses to disambiguate columns! But I can't expected to change every heart and mind, so I need to work with coders who will continue to adopt what I personally consider to be legacy join styles (and they may even refer to range variables as 'aliases'!). This is the nature of teamwork and not operating in a vacuum.

One of the criticisms of the SQL language is that the same result can be obtained using a number of semantically-equivalent syntaxes (some using relational algebra, some using the relational calculus), where choosing the 'best' one simply comes down to personal style. So I'm as comfortable with the 'old-style' joins as I am with `INNER`. Whether I'd take the time to rewrite them as `NATURAL` depends on context.

Comment: Avoid natural joins like the plague. They are error prone and difficult to debug. Plus, it's difficult to read them, down the road for new members on the development team. Also, they assume there's at most one FK between every pair of tables (really?) and that's not true for virtually all databases out there. They were not thought correctly since the beginning.

Comment: @TheImpaler: "they assume there's at most one FK between every pair of tables" - huh? You are surely aware one can natural join two tables that both lack a single FK. My personal plan for avoiding the plague: be aware of the risk (practically none in my environment) and mitigate where necessary (stay away from rural Madagascar). Same with natural join: if there is a risk someone might change a column name in a view (e.g. by adding a column) then manage the risk (e.g. expose/limit the columns I am expecting via CTEs). Intention of code is more explicit, code is easier to debug.

Comment: "...one can natural join two tables that both lack a single FK.." -- yes, so you agree with me. natural joins can only join a pair of tables with **zero or one** FK between them. However, any typical production application has multiple FKs between tables (it's very common) and natural joins cannot cope with that, something that probably happens 99.99% of the time. The designers just didn't think it through.

Comment: @TheImpaler: disagreeing (obvs). FKs (SQL DLL) do not enable or prevent joins (SQL DML) _by design_. Multiple FKs and joins that "cannot cope" are red herrings. If you post SQL DDL for two "multiple FK" tables along with your equi-join query and I'll rewrite the query to cope with natural join. Hint: I'll use CTEs to only project the required columns and rename them if necessary.