# How to convert in predicate of sql into linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How do I convert following query into Linq query--

```
SELECT ID FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @Temp)
```

Comment: how about spelling from correctly?

Comment: are you doing this with dynamic SQL ? what is @Temp? I don't get what kind of join you are trying to do in there. I suggest you have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373541/how-to-do-joins-in-linq-on-multiple-fields-in-single-join