# LINQ to SQL: Left join a table with itself and compute an average

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I'm trying to write the following query in LINQ to SQL. The table contains a list of sessions arranged by users, and the query computes the average amount of time between consecutive sessions for each user. It uses a left join, so that users who have only one session have a `NULL` value.

```
SELECT t1.workerId, AVG(DATEDIFF(s, t1.endTime, t2.startTime)) 
FROM e_userLongSessions t1 
LEFT JOIN e_userLongSessions t2 
ON t1.workerId = t2.workerId AND t1.sessionNum = t2.sessionNum - 1
GROUP BY t1.workerId
ORDER BY t1.workerId
```

Based on the questions [LINQ to SQL Left Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/700523/586086) and [How to do joins in LINQ on multiple fields in single join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373541/586086), I've gotten to the following query:

```
from s1 in gzClasses.e_userLongSessions
join s2 in gzClasses.e_userLongSessions
    on new {w = s1.workerId, n = s1.sessionNum} equals new {w = s2.workerId, n = s2.sessionNum - 1}
    into joined
from s2 in joined.DefaultIfEmpty(null)
group new {s1, s2} by s1.workerId into g                   
select g.Average(e => e.s2 == null ? (double?) null : (e.s2.startTime - e.s1.endTime).TotalSeconds);
```

I'm getting a `Unsupported overload used for query operator 'DefaultIfEmpty'` message. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LINQ query is not structured the same way the T-SQL query is. Specifically, you are only including `s` in the grouping. In fact, `s` is named in a misleading way. It should be `s2`. Include both:

```
from s1 in gzClasses.e_userLongSessions                    
join s2 in gzClasses.e_userLongSessions
    on new {w = s1.workerId, n = s1.sessionNum} 
equals new {w = s2.workerId, n = s2.sessionNum - 1}
    into joined                    
from s2Null in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()                    
group new {s1, s2Null} by s1.workerId into g                    
orderby g.Key // workerId
select g.Average(e => (e.s2Null.startTime - e.s1.endTime).TotalSeconds);
```

Now, you have data from both tables available in the aggregate. I don't think both of your queries are taking into account that `s2.startTime` can be null. But that is a bug that is not the point of the question.

Comment: That lambda expression has no idea what `s1` and `s2` are.

Comment: It's `e.s1/s2`. That code was quickly typed down and not tested. You'll get it to work.

Comment: I'm now getting a different error...see edits to question. Sorry, C# noob here. I don't understand what the first `s2` and second `s2` are representing.

Comment: `Unsupported overload used for query operator 'DefaultIfEmpty'` => Don't give it the `null` because LINQ can't deal with it. `null` is implicit if you don't give it an argument. Apart from that, the query looks good to me. If there's still an issue, it should be a small one. Fundamentally, this approach will work.