# Join into with column and variable value compared using Linq or Entity Framework queries

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I want to apply `join into` command using a column and a variable value.

here's the code (the partial part of the query where I have an issue):

```
 join p in db.user_tests on a.id equals p.test_id into g3
 from x3 in g3.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

This code works, but I also need to filter the `db.user_tests` by the user_id. I have that user_id in a variable userId inside the function.

So I decided to write the query as follows:

```
join p in db.user_tests on a.id equals p.test_id && userId equals p.user_id into g3
from x3 in g3.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

But I get `"Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type long and bool"` error.

I tried with `equal` but it throws several errors.

I also tried with [the two column join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373541/how-to-do-joins-in-linq-on-multiple-fields-in-single-join),  but I use a variable in the comparison so it doesn't work.

How can I use the join into with a column comparison and a variable at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join on several properties you should use anonymous objects for that:

```
join p in db.user_tests 
on new { a.id, userId } equals new { id = p.test_id, userId = p.user_id } into g3
from x3 in g3.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Also make sure that anonymous objects have properties with same types and names.

But thus `userId` is not part of your `a` object it makes no sense to use that variable as part of join. You can simply join on `test_id` and use filter by `user_id`:

```
join p in db.user_tests.Where(x => x.user_id == userId) 
on a.id equals np.test_id into g3
from x3 in g3.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: Yep, I am checking with the same types, because it through an error before. so I do casting and checking again.

Comment: @IdanShechter if order, names and types of anonymous objects are same, then query will be compiled and executed without any issues. And generated query will look like `ON a.Id = p.test_id AND @userId = p.user_id`, user Id will be passed as query parameter