# How to make linq lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, lambda

```
select a.ObjectFieldID,
       a.FieldName,
       b.RelationName 
  from tblMNG_Framework_ObjectField as a left join 
       tblMNG_Framework_ObjectRelation as b on a.ObjectID = b.RelatedObjectID 
                                           and a.ObjectFieldID = b.RelatedKeyFieldID 
 where a.ObjectID = 2 
   and a.Deleted = 0
```

Comment: what are you asking? This already is an expression. Or do you mean method-syntax instead of SQL-like-syntax?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I just want to this sql query convert to Linq LambdaExpression.

Comment: See Left outer join : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause

Comment: @jdweng thank you for your reply but this is Linq examples I want to linq lambda expression and I don't know How to make join include two and expression for example my example include join two criteria like this on a.ObjectID = b.RelatedObjectID  and a.ObjectFieldID = b.RelatedKeyFieldID

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Comment: [LINQ to SQL: Left join on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431739/linq-to-sql-left-join-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: @DragandDrop Sorry, this is not the answer I am looking for.I want linq LAMBDAEXPRESSION.your answer is LINQ.thank you

Comment: [How do you perform a left outer join using linq extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/how-do-you-perform-a-left-outer-join-using-linq-extension-methods). Note that my proposed dupe does include that already.

Comment: @Mustafa There is absolutely no difference between a linq query comprehension and a linq lambda expression. Why are you bent upon the lambda expression syntax? Is this some assignment?

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to Linq Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you? Also, `GroupJoin` is the equivalent of `join`...`into`.

Answer (score 0):

It's my quick code, I have no data to test so feedback me with your data sample if left join is not exact.

```
tblMNG_Framework_ObjectField.GroupJoin(tblMNG_Framework_ObjectRelation,
                a => new { JoinCol1 = a.ObjectID, JoinCol2 = a.ObjectFieldID },
                b => new { JoinCol1 = b.RelatedObjectID, JoinCol2 = b.RelatedKeyFieldID },
                (a, b) => new { a, b }).Where(x => x.a.ObjectID == 2 && x.a.Deleted == 0)
                .SelectMany(b => b.b.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (a, b) => new { a.a.ObjectID, a.a.FieldName, b.RelationName });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I get error like thi.  The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.GroupJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(IEnumerable<TOuter>, IEnumerable<TInner>, Func<TOuter, TKey>, Func<TInner, TKey>, Func<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: I have no data to test left join, so please if it's not work, provide a bit the data sample is ok

Comment: I get error like this : The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.GroupJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(IEnumerable<TOuter>, IEnumerable<TInner>, Func<TOuter, TKey>, Func<TInner, TKey>, Func<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Comment: It's work bro, check out my code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fId8qP

Comment: I still get error on GroupJoin syntax.I also compiled your code and there is no mistake :( thank your for everything

Comment: Yes you might check these references (System.Linq, System.Collections.Generic), these inputs as List, rebuild, clear caches,.... or even create a new console project one to make sure what the problem is.