# Include multiple ON in LINQ join

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

How to put multiple on in LINQ
Like

```
var retailTransactionDiscountTrans = 
    (from t1 in context.RETAILTRANSACTIONPAYMENTTRANS
     join t2 in context.RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLEs
     on t1.TRANSACTIONID equals t2.TRANSACTIONID && t1.STORE equals t2.STORE)....;
```

I just want to include other ON in LINQ for that join.

Comment: So can you not add another join?

Comment: is it the same like INNER JOIN RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE AS t2 
ON t2.TRANSACTIONID = t1.TRANSACTIONID 
AND t2.STORE = t1.STORE 
AND t2.TERMINAL = t1.TERMINAL 
AND t2.DATAAREAID = t1.DATAAREAID 
If I add multiple joins with the same table?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373541/how-to-do-joins-in-linq-on-multiple-fields-in-single-join

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here. on is used to reference a column thats common between the tables i don't see the point of having multiple on on the same join could you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate. Thanks for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do joins in LINQ on multiple fields in single join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373541/how-to-do-joins-in-linq-on-multiple-fields-in-single-join)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) for this purpose. Something like this:

```
on new { t1.TRANSACTIONID, t1.STORE } equals new { t2.TRANSACTIONID, t2.STORE }
```