# Get items with same values in properties in different list

Tags: c#

I have two list of the same type of object (X)

X has this properties:

- Id: int
- Name: string
- Month: string
- ISSPA: string

I want to get the items which has the same value in the properties Month and ISSPA.
For example:

List 1

```
Item 1 
{
   Id = 1, 
   Name = "John",
   Month = "October"
   ISSPA = "1234"
}

Item 2
{
   Id = 2, 
   Name = "Ryan",
   Month = "September"
   ISSPA = "1234"
}
```

List 2

```
Item 1 
{
   Id = 1, 
   Name = "Chris",
   Month = "September"
   ISSPA = "1234"
}
```

In this case I need to get Item 2 (List1) and Item 1 (List2).
I tried a lot of things to get something decent but all failed.

Comment: Could you share your code please. At least show what you tried, we can start from there

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins)

Comment: What's the difference between List 1 and List 2? Could the Item 1 from List 2 be added to List 1 instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do joins in LINQ on multiple fields in single join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373541/how-to-do-joins-in-linq-on-multiple-fields-in-single-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = list1
                .Concat(list2)
                .GroupBy(x => (x.Month, x.ISSPA))
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to search for these items in your lists. For example:

```
var filteredList = yourList.Where(x => x.Month == "September" && x.ISSPA == "1234").ToList();
```

Simply do the same thing for your second list and combine both results into a new list.