# Performing multiple joins in a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

Can someone help me translate the following SQL query into a LINQ format.

```
SELECT *
FROM "Table1" AS t1
INNER JOIN "Table2" AS t2 ON t1."t2Id" = t2."Id"
LEFT JOIN "Table3" AS t3 ON t2."Id" = t3."t2Id" AND t1."Code" = t3."Code"
WHERE r."Code" = 61000
```

I need to link the Table3 with Table2 by Id and with Table1 by Code.
Usage EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions in priority, but not necessarily.

I try this

```
var query =
    from t1 in dbContext.Table1
    join t2 in dbContext.Table2 on t1.t2Id equals t2.Id
    join t3 in dbContext.Table3 on new **{ t2.Id, t1.Code }** equals new { t3.t2Id, t3.Code } into j1
    from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { t1.SampleId };
```

But have CS1600 error because of this `**{ t2.Id, t1.Code }**`

This example doesn't fit, because it's incorrect link

```
var query =
    from t1 in dbContext.Table1
    join t2 in dbContext.Table2 on t1.t2Id equals t2.Id
    join t3 in dbContext.Table3 on new **{ t1.t2Id, t1.Code }** equals new { t3.t2Id, t3.Code } into j1
    from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { t1.SampleId };
```

`where t1.Code == t3.Code` is not intended to be used, because t3 can be null

Many thanks

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373541/how-to-do-joins-in-linq-on-multiple-fields-in-single-join and see if it solves the problem. you might have to use new {X1=t2.Id, Y1=t1.code} equals  new {X1=t3.t2Id, Y1=t3.code}

Comment: Were you able to get it working