# Compile error on simple compound conditional in LINQ to SQL join

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

For some reason I am getting a "Query body must end with a select clause or a group clause" compile error on what seems to be a simple compound conditional in the following linq-to-sql query:

```
using (var db = new CaremcDB(Database.Conn))
{
 var taxids = from p in db.ProviderTaxIds 
      join c in db.CustomerProviders
      on customerId equals c.CustomerId && p.Id equals c.ProviderId
      select p;

 return taxids.ToList<ProviderTaxIds>();
}
```

It chokes on the "&& p.Id equals c.ProviderId" clause for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried using == instead of equals?

Comment: Using == instead of equals creates a different error: "The name 'p' is not in scope on the right side of 'equals'"

Comment: how about adding parenthesis around  customerId equals c.CustomerId && p.Id equals c.ProviderId

Comment: I get the following errors when using parenthesis: 1. ) expected  2. Invalid expression term ')'  3. A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause  4. : expected

Comment: is `customerId` a different input or should it have been `p.customerId`?

Comment: See [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345427/linq-to-sql-join-multiple-columns-from-the-same-table) for answers

Comment: Yes. It is parameter on the the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `customerId` is an external input to the query. Move that to a `where` clause.

```
...
on p.Id equals c.ProviderId  
where customerId == c.CustomerId
select p;
```

Comment: That works for some reason. But it also compiles if I remove the "&& p.Id equals c.ProviderId" (which isn't what I want, but just testing the ability to compile.) It is very puzzeling as it seems this should be rather straight-forward.

Comment: @Billy, The `&&` portion is the problem. Another user posted a way to do a compound-field join via anonymous typing, but you really don't need to do that in this specific case.

Comment: Using the where clause works. I take it that && is not allowed on a join for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

try this, the parameter names just need to match in the anonymous object

`join c in db.CustomerProviders on new { customerId, p.Id } equals new { customerId = c.CustomerId, Id= c.ProviderId }`