# join three tables with LINQ on different columns and print sum at the end

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, join

I have 3 tables as shown.

```
var table1 = new[]
{
    new { Col1 = 1, Col2 = 'A', },
};

var table2 = new[]
{
    new { Col1 = 'A', Col2 = 'X', },
    new { Col1 = 'B', Col2 = 'Y', },
};

var table3 = new[]
{
    new { Col1 = 1, Col3 = 'X', Col4 = 100, },
    new { Col1 = 1, Col3 = 'Y', Col4 = 200, },
    new { Col1 = 2, Col3 = 'X', Col4 = 400, }
};
```

Row needed -> 1, A, X, 100

I tried [How to join 3 tables with linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933985/how-to-join-3-tables-with-linq) which is not working.

Please help with the exact code. I am new to SQL.

Comment: Put your attempt in the question, explain why what you have isn't working.

Comment: Do you want an example in LINQ or SQL? It's not clear from the question.

Comment: I need LINQ @Andrei15193

Comment: @Larnu I attempted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933985/how-to-join-3-tables-with-linq

Comment: @RPD well, that should work. What's giving you trouble specifically?

Comment: @RPD - The linked answer is exactly what you need to do. What wasn't working?

Comment: Put ***your*** attempt in the question, @RPD ... Clearly you've not altered the solution correctly when you implemented it, so if you show us your *actual* attempt we can tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: @Larnu,  sorry for confusion 
select new MyProjectViewModel { myClassProperty = IShouldGetValue100 }  Please help me to define IShouldGetValue100
I want 100 because of table value.

Comment: @Enigmativity
select new MyProjectViewModel { myClassProperty = IShouldGetValue100 } Please help me to define IShouldGetValue100. I want 100 because of table value.

Comment: @Enigmativity
select new MyProjectViewModel { myClassProperty = IShouldGetValue100 } Please help me to define IShouldGetValue100. I want 100 because of table value.

Currently, I am getting 300 (because 100+200).

Comment: @RPD - Did you try my code? It only returns 100.

Comment: @Enigmativity I had to add where t3.Col1 == t1.Col1 before the select part in your query. That worked! Thank you! If where is not added then rows like 2 'X' 300 in table3 poses problem. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: @RPD - My query worked given your data. What made you think it needed an extra `where` to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
var table1 = new[]
{
    new { Col1 = 1, Col2 = 'A', },
};

var table2 = new[]
{
    new { Col1 = 'A', Col2 = 'X', },
    new { Col1 = 'B', Col2 = 'Y', },
};

var table3 = new[]
{
    new { Col1 = 1, Col3 = 'X', Col4 = 100, },
    new { Col1 = 1, Col3 = 'Y', Col4 = 200, },
};

var query =
    from t1 in table1
    join t2 in table2 on t1.Col2 equals t2.Col1
    join t3 in table3 on t2.Col2 equals t3.Col3
    where t3.Col1 == t1.Col1
    select new
    {
        t1.Col1, Col22 = t1.Col2, Col23 = t2.Col2, t3.Col4,
    };
```

I get:

```
1 A X 100
```

However, with your naming convention of `ColX` and repeating values it has made a few things ambiguous. It would have been nice to have properly named fields with clearly distinct values.

Comment: select new MyProjectViewModel {
 myClassProperty =  IShouldGetValue100
}

Please help me to define IShouldGetValue100

Comment: @RPD - What do you mean by "define IShouldGetValue100"?

Comment: I have edited your kind suggestion to answer my question. I have also edited the question where I have added a third row in the data. For such data row "where condition" is needed.