# Another unknown column name error in ON clause

Tags: mysql, join

Query:

```
SELECT  c.title AS title
            , c.introtext AS body
            , c.state AS state
            , c.created AS created
            , c.created_by AS uid
            , c.modified AS modified
            , c.modified_by AS modified_uid
            , c.published AS published
            , c.published_by AS published_uid
            , jos_categories.title AS category
FROM
          jos_content AS c, jos_categories
INNER JOIN jos_categories AS jc
ON c.sectionid = jc.section
WHERE c.sectionid = 7
```

I am sure that sectionid column exists, but I am getting error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'c.sectionid' in 'on
>   clause'   0.000 sec

I saw this topic: [MySQL unknown column in ON clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065985/mysql-unknown-column-in-on-clause) but I can't solve it too.

Comment: please ensure that jos_content table contains the column sectionid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your FROM clause to:

```
FROM   jos_content AS c
INNER JOIN jos_categories AS jc 
ON c.sectionid = jc.section 
WHERE c.sectionid = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You preform the join between `jos_categories` and `jos_categories AS jc`:

```
jos_content AS c, jos_categories
INNER JOIN jos_categories AS jc
ON c.sectionid = jc.section
```

but `c` is `jos_content`...