# Unknown column 'R.movie_name' in 'on clause' for Inner join with subquery

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I tried to rename the table using join, but I'm running into the `Unknown column 'R.movie_name' in 'on clause'`. I referenced this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11912903/7327018) to correct, but I'm still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

**My SQL query**

```
  SELECT R.movie_name, AVG(S.similarity*R.rating)
 FROM Ratings AS R, Similarity S
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT R.movie_name
    FROM Ratings R, Users U 
    WHERE U.name = 'Adam Brody' AND U.user_id != R.user_id
    ) AS MoviesAdamDidntWatch ON  R.movie_name = MoviesAdamDidntWatch.movie_name
 GROUP BY R.movie_name;
```

**My Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE Users (user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE Ratings (user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                      rating INTEGER NOT NULL,
                      movie_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY(user_id, movie_name),
                      FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id));
CREATE TABLE Similarity (user1_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                      user2_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                      similarity FLOAT,
                      PRIMARY KEY (user1_id, user2_id),
                      FOREIGN KEY (user1_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id),
                      FOREIGN KEY (user2_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id));
```

Comment: Im not sure so I'm posting this as a comment. I think you should remove the `"AS"` in `FROM Ratings AS R, Similarity S`

Comment: `R` specified as an alias twice in query, one more issue how do you relate Similarity table with query, right now its doing cross product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used R twice as Alias in your query . You can fix it by replacing outer R with some other alias. like -

```
SELECT Rtg.movie_name, AVG(S.similarity*Rtg.rating)
 FROM Ratings AS Rtg, Similarity S
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT R.movie_name
    FROM Ratings R, Users U 
    WHERE U.name = 'Adam Brody' AND U.user_id != R.user_id
    ) AS MoviesAdamDidntWatch ON  Rtg.movie_name = MoviesAdamDidntWatch.movie_name
 GROUP BY Rtg.movie_name;
```

But your query is not optimised, Consider optimising it by removing redundant inner query and cross products.I may help you with it if you post your table structure.