# MySQL: JOIN multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have the following query I am trying to join 2 tables (' Industry' , 'Country' ) on 2 conditions, but it gives me the following error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'i.id' in 'on clause'

Does anybody know how should I tackle this?

```
SELECT c.name AS country_name, i.name as industry_name, num_projects, num_consultants, admin_rating
    FROM    industry i, country c 
    JOIN   (SELECT   pc.country_id, pi.industry_id, COUNT(p.id) AS num_projects
            FROM     project p, project_country pc, project_industry pi
            where p.id = pc.project_id and pi.project_id=p.id
            GROUP BY pc.country_id,pi.industry_id) x ON x.country_id = c.id  and x.industry_id=i.id
    JOIN   (SELECT   u.country_id,ie.industry_id, COUNT(u.id) AS num_consultants  
            FROM     user u, consultant_profile, industry_experience ie
            WHERE    u.is_active = 1 AND u.type = 0 and
                     ie.consultant_profile_id= consultant_profile.id 
                     and u.id= consultant_profile.id 
            GROUP BY u.country_id,ie.industry_id) y ON y.country_id = c.id and y.industry_id = i.id order by num_projects DESC limit 20;
```

EDIT the table structure is as following:

- **industry**             - id
- **project_industry**     - industry_id, project_id
- **industry_experience**  - consultant_profile_id, industry_id
- **consultant_profile**   - id,user_id

Comment: `industry` table have `id` column ?

Comment: do you have column name called id in industry table

Comment: can you please post your industry table columns?

Comment: Can you post your `industry` table structure?

Comment: I will edit the post with the columns from each table

Comment: it is better to provide sql fiddle with all table `CREATE` statement. and you should avoid using `FROM t1, t2, t3` that should be `JOIN`, something like `FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.t2_id=t2.id JOIN t3 ON t1.t3_id=t3.id`

Comment: See if this solution fixes it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065985/mysql-unknown-column-in-on-clause

Comment: are you trying to group by *admin_rating* ? what table this column belongs to?

Comment: are you sure about this condition? `where p.id = pc.project_id and pi.industry_id=p.id` so **p.id** equal to **pc.project_id** and at the same time to  **pi.industry_id**?

Comment: @ALex admin_rating wasn't relevant so I removed it for now. I edited the SQL to make it more clear, and thanks for points it out it should have been pi.proejct_id = p.id

Answer (score 1):

Since you still did not provide any sql fiddle
you can start from my one:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c0569/1

```
SELECT   pc.country_id, pi.industry_id, 
  COUNT(p.id) AS num_projects,
  COUNT(u.id) AS num_consultants
  FROM   project p
INNER JOIN project_country pc
ON p.id = pc.project_id
INNER JOIN project_industry pi
ON pi.project_id=p.id
INNER JOIN `user` u
ON u.is_active = 1 AND u.type = 0 
   and u.country_id = pc.country_id
INNER JOIN industry_experience ie
ON u.id = ie.consultant_profile_id
  AND ie.industry_id = pi.industry_id
GROUP BY pc.country_id, pi.industry_id
```

if you will add some data into that fiddle we can discuss deeper