# MySQL - Unknown column in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, inner-join, multiple-tables

```
var FieldTypeRetrievalQuery = '
SELECT
  modules.ModuleId,
  modules.ModuleName,
  submodules.SubModuleId,
  submodules.SubModuleName,
  modules_submodules.ModulesSubModulesId,
  field_config.FieldId,
  field_config.Form_Field_Name,
  SubModuleFieldConfigId
FROM modules
  INNER JOIN modules_submodules ON modules.ModuleId = modules_submodules.Modules_ModuleId
  INNER JOIN submodules ON submodules.SubModuleId = modules_submodules.SubModules_SubModuleId
  INNER JOIN field_config ON field_config.FieldId = submodule_field_config.Field_Config_FieldId
  INNER JOIN submodules AS som ON som.SubModuleId = submodule_field_config.SubModule_SubModuleId
  INNER JOIN submodule_field_config ON submodule_field_config.Field_Config_FieldId = field_config.FieldId;
';
```

This is my query and im getting following error and field_config is not a direct child table of modules

> Unknown column 'submodule_field_config.Field_Config_FieldId' in 'on clause'

How do I fix it?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - check the field exists and that it is spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MySQL unknown column in ON clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065985/mysql-unknown-column-in-on-clause) looks like it could solve your problem.

"Don't mix ANSI-89 style and ANSI-92 style joins. They have different precedence which can lead to confusing errors, and that is what has happened here"