# MySQL unknown column in my query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I have the following MySQL query

```
select 
    keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id, 
    MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo), 
    sum(keliones_lapas.uzdarbis) as Got, 
    coalesce(Suma, 0) Suma, 
    (sum(keliones_lapas.uzdarbis) - coalesce(Suma, 0)) Total
from keliones_lapas
left join (select Vairuotas, MONTH(Data_islaidu), sum(Suma) as Spend from 
    islaidos group by Vairuotas, MONTH(Data_islaidu))
    islaidos on 
    keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id=islaidos.Vairuotas and 
    MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo)=MONTH(islaidos.Data_islaidu)
group by keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id, MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo), Suma
order by keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id, MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo);
```

And i'm getting this error:

## 1054 - Unknown column 'Suma' in 'field list'

I know that this issue is known but i do not know how to fix it by my self.
[This is the cause of the issue which is solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065985)

And i can provide with the fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e76ef9/8

Comment: The fiddle is giving the error Unknown column 'Suma' in 'field list'

Comment: Ye i mean i need to solve this, does not matter the error it provides. i am not sure how to solve either field list or other one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to alias all of the calculated columns in the sub-query, and then you can reference those aliases in the `ON` clause. Here is the SQL from your fiddle with the Data_islaidu and Suma columns aliased:

```
select keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id, MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo), sum(keliones_lapas.uzdarbis) as Got, coalesce(Suma, 0) AS Spend, (sum(keliones_lapas.uzdarbis) - coalesce(Suma, 0)) Total
from keliones_lapas
left join (
    select 
        Vairuotas, 
        MONTH(Data_islaidu) as Data_islaidu, 
        sum(Suma) as Suma 
     from islaidos 
     group by Vairuotas, MONTH(Data_islaidu)) islaidos 
on keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id = islaidos.Vairuotas 
and MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo) = MONTH(islaidos.Data_islaidu)
group by keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id, MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo), Suma
order by keliones_lapas.Vairuot_Id, MONTH(keliones_lapas.Data_darbo);
```

Comment: Thank you that solved the errors!! 
Could you look into my sql and see why he does not count Spend?

Comment: It could be because islaidos.Suma has a lot of nulls. Try SUM(COALESCE(Suma, 0)) AS Suma in your subquery to get 0's instead of nulls.