# mysql5.7 query with multiple tables error

Tags: mysql-error-1054

> ```
> mysql> desc apn_licence;
> +------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
> | Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
> +------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
> | vdomain    | char(32)         | NO   | PRI | test              |       |
> | vhost      | char(32)         | NO   | PRI |                   |       |
> | licence    | char(64)         | NO   |     |                   |       |
> | tcpport    | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0                 |       |
> | srvtype    | tinyint(4)       | NO   |     | 0                 |       |
> | auxcmd     | tinyint(3)       | YES  |     | 0                 |       |
> | agentuid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 1                 |       |
> | owneruid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 1                 |       |
> | sno        | char(32)         | YES  |     | 0                 |       |
> | pno        | char(32)         | YES  |     | 0                 |       |
> | updatedate | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
> | builddate  | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
> +------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
> 12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> desc apn_agent;
> +--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
> +--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | uid          | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
> | euid         | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | 0       |                |
> | username     | char(16)            | NO   | UNI |         |                |
> | password     | char(16)            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
> | priv_licence | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
> | priv_admin   | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
> | priv_srv     | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
> | plant_asign  | int(11)             | YES  |     | 0       |                |
> +--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> 8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> desc apn_routine;
> +------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
> | Field      | Type                 | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
> +------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
> | acxid      | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | 0                 |       |
> | sid        | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | 0                 |       |
> | wanipaddr  | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | 0                 |       |
> | udpport    | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 8400              |       |
> | serial     | bigint(20) unsigned  | YES  |     | 0                 |       |
> | nserial    | bigint(20) unsigned  | YES  |     | 0                 |       |
> | rivec      | char(32)             | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
> | stat       | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 4                 |       |
> | vtype      | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 0                 |       |
> | gwtype     | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 2                 |       |
> | vactlevel  | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | 0                 |       |
> | vnatlevel  | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | 0                 |       |
> | vdomain    | char(32)             | NO   |     |                   |       |
> | vhost      | char(32)             | NO   |     |                   |       |
> | vsubkey    | char(32)             | YES  |     | public            |       |
> | passwd     | char(64)             | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
> | gwmac      | char(18)             | YES  | MUL | 00:0D:B0:00:00:00 |       |
> | vsubnet    | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | 0                 |       |
> | vsubmask   | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | 0                 |       |
> | vgwip      | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | 0                 |       |
> | vgwnexthop | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | 0                 |       |
> | groupstamp | timestamp            | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
> | joinstamp  | timestamp            | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
> +------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
> 23 rows in set (0.00 sec)
> ```

With mysql-3.23.58

```sql
select l.*, a.username from apn_licence as l, apn_agent as a 
  left join apn_routine as r on l.vdomain=r.vdomain and l.vhost=r.vhost 
  where
    l.agentuid=a.uid 
  group by l.vdomain 
  order by l.tcpport DESC,l.vdomain,l.vhost;
```

is OK.
But with mysql-5.7.26,it get the error as:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'l.vdomain' in 'on clause'

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` if you are not selecting any aggregates?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are `invisible garbage characters` in your query.

Try retyping the query (don't copy and paste or you'll most likely include the garbage character) and most probably it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,I found the answer in
[[MySQL unknown column in ON clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065985/mysql-unknown-column-in-on-clause][1])

The correct query is

```
select l.*, a.username from (apn_licence as l, apn_agent as a) 
  left join apn_routine as r on l.vdomain=r.vdomain and l.vhost=r.vhost 
  where
    l.agentuid=a.uid 
  group by l.vdomain 
  order by l.tcpport DESC,l.vdomain,l.vhost;
```