# MySQL - subquery in WHERE unknown column in join (count in subquery)

Tags: mysql

The following query is giving me this error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'jobs.id' in 'on clause'


SELECT clinics.id as cid, clinics.name, clinics.address AS clinicAddress,
            clinics.post_code as clinicZip, clinics.city AS clinicCity, clinics.region,
            countries.full_name AS country,
            jobs.name AS jobName, jobs.created_at AS jobCreatedAt, jobs.from AS jobStarts,
            jobs.description AS jobDescription, jobs.rates, jobs.max_applicants, jobs.created_at,
            locum_types.name AS locumName,
            job_statuses.name AS statusName,
            CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) AS userName, users.title AS userTitle,
            roles.name AS roleName            
            FROM clinics
            JOIN countries ON countries.id = clinics.country_id
            JOIN jobs ON clinics.id = jobs.clinics_id
            JOIN users ON users.id = jobs.users_id
            JOIN roles ON roles.id = users.roles_id
            JOIN locum_types ON locum_types.id = jobs.locum_types_id
            JOIN job_statuses ON job_statuses.id = jobs.statuses_id
            WHERE (LOWER(`clinics`.`city`) like '%abbey%'
            OR LOWER(`clinics`.`post_code`) like '%abbey%'
            OR LOWER(`clinics`.`region`) like '%abbey%')
            AND jobs.to >= '2020-01-31 07:53:48'
            AND applicants IN (SELECT COUNT(user_jobs_application.id) as applicants 
                FROM user_jobs_application
                JOIN user_jobs_application as jobApplication ON user_jobs_application.jobs_id = jobs.id
                HAVING applicants < jobs.max_applicants)
            LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

I am trying to count all jobs in the **user_jobs_application** table and check if the count is lesser than the **max_applicants** in **jobs** table.

The structure of the **jobs** table is following:

```
id
max_applicants
created_at
```

The **user_jobs_application** table (this is pivot table):

```
id
users_id
jobs_id
```

Basically I need to count all applications for the job and check if it within limits (**max_applicants**).
Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: in the inner SQL query, you have "SELECT COUNT(user_jobs_application.id) as applicants FROM user_jobs_application JOIN user_jobs_application" the join part  should be "JOIN jobs"

Comment: You have used "JOIN user_jobs_application as jobApplication" but where is the jobApplication used?

Comment: As an aside, it seems unlikely that you would be using a case sensitive collation

Comment: Might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065985/mysql-unknown-column-in-on-clause

Comment: I'd post an answer if I could get the ERD. In my knowledge, the order of the JOIN's usually creates this error. For example, If I ever have tables A->B->C with no connection between A and C I need to JOIN B to C first before joining A to B in order to have the result from A-B-C. Check for cross JOIN's !

Comment: I have a few questions. When you do `AND applicants IN ( ..` where does the column `applicants` coming from? And what value does it hold? `id` or total count of `applicants`? If that so, isn't it strange to use `IN`.. because it seems that you wanted find a bunch of `id` instead.

Comment: @tcadidot0 I need to count if number of users applied to the job (applicants) is lesser than maximum user allowed for that job (jobs.max_applicants)

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
JOIN user_jobs_application as jobApplication ON user_jobs_application.id = jobs.id
```

Instead of :

```
JOIN user_jobs_application as jobApplication ON user_jobs_application.jobs_id = jobs.id
```

Answer (score 1):

The sub-query that you did after `applicants IN` is being treated separately from the outer query so it doesn't "see" the `jobs` table as it is out of it's scope.

Why don't you start with a simple query first. Just to get the result you wanted. Focus on the two tables only. You might use a query like below:

```
SELECT jobs.id, jobs.max_applicants, uja.jobs_id, uja.total_applicants 
FROM   jobs 
JOIN   (SELECT jobs_id,COUNT(*) total_applicants FROM user_jobs_application GROUP BY jobs_id) uja
ON     uja.jobs_id = jobs.id
WHERE  jobs.to >= '2020-01-31 07:53:48'
AND    uja.total_applicants > jobs.max_applicants;
```

Make the count from `user_jobs_application` table into a sub-query then join it with `jobs` table. See if this can return the result you wanted. If it does, then you can implement this into your original query. Probably something like this:

```
SELECT clinics.id AS cid, clinics.name, clinics.address AS clinicAddress,
            clinics.post_code AS clinicZip, clinics.city AS clinicCity, clinics.region,
            countries.full_name AS country,
            jobs.name AS jobName, jobs.created_at AS jobCreatedAt, jobs.from AS jobStarts,
            jobs.description AS jobDescription, jobs.rates, jobs.max_applicants, jobs.created_at,
            locum_types.name AS locumName,
            job_statuses.name AS statusName,
            CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) AS userName, users.title AS userTitle,
            roles.name AS roleName            
            FROM clinics
            JOIN countries ON countries.id = clinics.country_id
            JOIN jobs ON clinics.id = jobs.clinics_id
            JOIN users ON users.id = jobs.users_id
            JOIN roles ON roles.id = users.roles_id
            JOIN locum_types ON locum_types.id = jobs.locum_types_id
            JOIN job_statuses ON job_statuses.id = jobs.statuses_id
            /*Insert here*/
            JOIN 
            (SELECT jobs_id,COUNT(*) total_applicants 
             FROM   user_jobs_application GROUP BY jobs_id) uja ON  uja.jobs_id = jobs.id
            /**/      
            WHERE (LOWER(`clinics`.`city`) LIKE '%abbey%'
            OR LOWER(`clinics`.`post_code`) LIKE '%abbey%'
            OR LOWER(`clinics`.`region`) LIKE '%abbey%')
            AND jobs.to >= '2020-01-31 07:53:48'
            /*and add the condition here*/
            AND uja.total_applicants > jobs.max_applicants
            /**/
            LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```