# How are these two SQL statements different?

Tags: mysql, sql

1:

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT table_one.row 
FROM table_one 
INNER JOIN table_two 
ON table_two.row = $id");
```

2:

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT table_one.row 
FROM table_one, table_two 
WHERE table_two.row = $id");
```

Are these just two ways of writing the same thing?

Comment: You should research inner join, look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: To translate both query statements: show all records from table_one as long as some record somewhere in table_two has an ID of $x.  Did I get that right?

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer: nope

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer: there will be all records from t1 **multiplied** to the set of t2.row = id. It is called cartesian product.

Comment: @zerkms: just speaking strictly on the expected results, especially when the join is on an arbitrary value rather than any fields with matching values.  Also, just testing the queries shows these same results.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer: oh yes. Missed that fact. If `row` is a PK - then you're right, sorry.

Comment: @zerkms: actually, you're correct.  Well, it's either a cartesian result or nothing depending on the existence of that arbitrary value in t2.  I think I'll just slowly back away from this post now.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer: yep, cartesian of `table1 x {0|1}row`

Comment: @jon3laze I think your comment is out of date because I went to w3fools just now and it looks like they've rescinded their previous objections to w3schools (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: @ryvantage You are correct. I have removed the comment as it is no longer relevant. Thank you for notifying me.

Comment: @jon3laze no prob. I'm going to delete these comments in a couple of hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both achieve the same results but with different approaches. Though you are misusing the ON clause.

I would suggest something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT table_one.row 
FROM table_one 
INNER JOIN table_two 
ON table_one.id = table_two.id
WHERE table_two.row = $id");
```

Quote from mysql site:

> The conditional_expr used with ON is any conditional expression of the form that can be used in a WHERE clause. Generally, you should use the ON clause for conditions that specify how to join tables, and the WHERE clause to restrict which rows you want in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, queries are semantically the same.

Though both produce cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

The first query is using the newer ANSI-92 syntax, while your second in using the older ANSI-89 syntax. Both should produce identical results.

Moreover, read this post: [Why isn't SQL ANSI-92 standard better adopted over ANSI-89?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334201/why-isnt-sql-ansi-92-standard-better-adopted-over-ansi-89)

Personally, and I hope most would agree, I prefer ANSI-92 which uses the "JOIN" syntax. As was mentioned in the referenced post, it lets you separate your JOIN constraints from your WHERE or filter constraints which improves readability.

Comment: The ansi-92 syntax will allow left joins also, which is harder using the older syntax. It also makes the query easier to understand, so you don't mistakenly get the cartesian product that zerkms mentions.