# mysql join query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have two tables that I need to join. These are:

- `art`

  ```
  id | art
  --------
  1  | A
  2  | B
  3  | C
  4  | D
  5  | E
  6  | F
  7  | G
  8  | H
  9  | I
  ```

  and
- `Sess`

  ```
  artid | sessid
  --------------
  1     | 1
  2     | 1
  3     | 1
  4     | 1
  1     | 2
  4     | 2
  5     | 2
  6     | 2
  1     | 3
  2     | 3
  7     | 3
  4     | 3
  ```

where `Sess.artid` is a foregin key to `art.id`.

From the tables above we can see that there are 3 sessions: `A,B,C,D`, `A,D,E,F` and `A,B,G,D`.
I want to get a ranking of the arts that occur along with art `A`. Something like:

```
D=3
B=2
```

How could I form such a query in mysql or postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join twice the session table to get the article sharing the same session.
Then join one time with article for the filter clause, and another time to get the name of the other article in the other session.

```
SELECT aSameSession.art, count(*)
FROM art a
    INNER JOIN Sess s
        ON a.id = s.artid
    INNER JOIN Sess sSameArticle
            ON sSameArticle.sessid = s.sessid
    INNER JOIN art aSameSession
        ON sSameArticle.artid = aSameSession.id
WHERE A.art = 'A'
AND aSameSession.art <> 'A'
GROUP BY aSameSession.art
```

Output :

```
B   2
C   1
D   3
E   1
F   1
G   1
```

This version could be a little difficult to understand, so here a version just with the ID of the article, which is much more simple :

```
SELECT sSameArticle.artid, count(*)
FROM Sess s
    INNER JOIN Sess sSameArticle
        ON sSameArticle.sessid = s.sessid
WHERE s.artid = 1
AND sSameArticle.artid != 1
GROUP BY sSameArticle.artid
```

Output :

```
2   2
3   1
4   3
5   1
6   1
7   1
```

Adding the name of the article is just cosmetic.

Comment: Thanks Scorpi0. Your query seems to be on track. However, I haven't managed to get it to work as I want. I may be doing something wrong though. Should I include those inned joins nested as you wrote?

Comment: What output do you have ? You don't have to write inner join indent like me.

Comment: By running the query bellow I get an empty result set:

SELECT aSameSession.art, count(*) AS rank
FROM articles a
    INNER JOIN Sess s
        ON a.id = s.artid
            INNER JOIN art aSameSession
                ON s.artid = aSameSession.id
WHERE a.art = 'A'
AND aSameSession.art != 'A'
GROUP BY aSameSession.art

Comment: No result with this neither. I also get an empty result back.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! This definitely does the job for me. It also does not include a rank to itself and it's faster than ADW's query.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
select art,count(*)
from sessid
  left join art on art.id=artid
where sessid in (select sessid from sess where artid=1)
group by artid;
```

?

Comment: @Sfairas Accept the answer, when it is exactly what you needed!

Comment: This will work in MySQL but not sure about Postgres. Scorpi0's answer is better I think.

Comment: Scorpi0's answer seems to be on the right track. However, I haven't managed to get to work as I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.art, count(*) as ranking
FROM art a, sess s
WHERE a.id = s.artid
group by a.art
order by count(*) DESC;
```

For a statement in ANSI-92 syntax have a look at Konerak's answer.

Comment: This is correct, but try teaching the [ANSI-92 syntax instead of the old ANSI-89 syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334201/why-isnt-sql-ansi-92-standard-better-adopted-over-ansi-89).

Comment: You're right. I tend to use ANSI-89 because I find it much more readable. But that's probably only because I am a creature of habit.

There are good reasons for using ANSI-92 syntax...so +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Example of table structure and join queries on PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE arts (
    arts_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE sessions (
    sessions_id integer NOT NULL,
    arts_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES arts
);


SELECT arts.name, count(sessions_id)
FROM arts
JOIN sessions USING (arts_id)
GROUP BY arts.name
ORDER BY count(sessions_id) DESC;
```