# SQL Query for SUM Function

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have two tables Loan and Member. Now in Loan i have column totalamount and in Member i have column as membertype and in Loan i have various loan according to membertype. Now I want to use a SUM function to calculate totalamount according to the memtype.

I tried something as follows :

```
select sum(totalamount) from loan,member where member.mem_type='Regular'
```

Comment: Memberid of member table is a foreign key in Loan Table

Comment: Please use [ANSI 92 join style syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334201/why-isnt-sql-ansi-92-standard-better-adopted-over-ansi-89).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this:

```
select sum(totalamount) AS Total 
from loan
JOIN member ON Memberid=loan.Memberid   
where member.mem_type='Regular'
```

Or if you want to select `mem_type` as well then something like this:

```
select sum(totalamount) AS Total,member.mem_type 
from loan
JOIN member ON Memberid=loan.Memberid   
where member.mem_type='Regular'
GROUP BY member.mem_type
```