# How to avoid this complex query?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am designing a site like pinterest ( for study ) and I want to know what query I have to do at the homepage to show the user's stream.

I have created these 6 tables:

```
users
boards
pictures
boards_pictures ( many-to-many table )
followers
comments
```

And in home, I do this query to get all followers' pictures.

```
SELECT users.username, pictures.link, comments.comment, boards.title
FROM boards_pictures, pictures, followers, users, comments, boards 
WHERE ( boards_pictures.id_user = followers.id_following ) 
  AND ( boards_pictures.id_picture = pictures.id ) 
  AND ( followers.id_user = $_session['userid'] ) 
  AND ( users.id = followers.id_following )
  AND ( comments.picture_id = pictures.id )
  AND ( boards.id = boards_pictures.boards_id )
```

Is there a way to avoid this complex query ( a JOIN with 6 tables ) ?

Comment: It's a little difficult to answer this without knowing the table structure of each table.

Comment: join? I cannot see even 1 single JOIN

Comment: That doesn't come close to a complex query (I was revising one a 1000 lines long earlier today) If you need all six tables join to all of them, but do not ever use implicit joins they are very poor programming practice and a SQL antipattern. No sense learning incorrectly, use explicit joins only from now on.

Comment: Why is that a complex query? What would make it not complex? Also you might want to consider using ANSI-92 style joins.

Comment: @HLGEM do you mean that he should do the 6 joins instead of the above implicit join? (is that perhaps how the engine will execute it?) I'm actually asking.

Comment: @Keyser see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334201/why-isnt-sql-ansi-92-standard-better-adopted-over-ansi-89

Comment: @ConradFrix Was hoping for a more revolutionizing answer :p, but thanks for the perfect link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here're the DDL statements deduced from your query:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id integer, username varchar(30));
CREATE TABLE boards (id integer, title varchar(30));
CREATE TABLE pictures (id integer, link varchar(90));
CREATE TABLE boards_pictures (
  id_user integer,
  id_picture integer,
  boards_id integer);
CREATE TABLE followers (id_user integer, id_following integer);
CREATE TABLE comments (picture_id integer, comment varchar(350));
```

You're mixing column naming styles here, compare `users.id`, `followers.id_user`, `comments.picture_id` and `board_pictures.id_picture` (last 2 are quite misleading). The more tables you'll have, the more attention you'll have to pay on how column is named. It's better to stick to a single common pattern, `picture_id` or `user_id` being most appropriate in my view.

Your query is not complicated, except you're using [implicit join notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join). It is not the recommended way, as there's a chance to miss some predicates and end up with [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) of 2 (or more) tables.

Your query can be rewritten like this:

```
SELECT u.username, p.link, c.comment, b.title
  FROM boards_pictures bp
  JOIN pictures p ON p.id = bp.id_picture
  JOIN followers f ON bp.id_user = f.id_following
  JOIN users u ON u.id = f.id_following
  JOIN comments c ON c.picture_id = p.id
  JOIN boards b ON b.id = bp.boards_id
WHERE f.id_user = $_session['userid'];
```

As you see now, query is really simple and has only one predicate.
I've created a testbed without data on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cea8b/2).

In my view your structure is quite good. There's no need to change neither table design nor this query.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a very simple query, just many tables.

Rather than trying to retrieve everything in one big query, which will result in much duplicated data in your output, I would do one query to retrieve user/board/picture info, another query for followers, and another query for comments.

Also, you can use ANSI syntax for better readability.

Comment: In this way, I need to do one query for each following and one query for comments of each picture. So, If in homepage will be showed 50 last pictures of my following, then I need to do 1 query to retrieve followings's pictures + 50 queries to retrieve comments of each pictures.

Comment: no, you would do one query that retrieves comments for all 50 pictures