# The effect of a select with multiple tables in FROM is the same as INNER JOIN but what is the ON clause then?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1,
    table2
```

I know this is somewhat equivalent to:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1
INNER JOIN
    table2
ON ???
```

However, what would be the resulting ON clause for the join?

### Update

After some testing in SSMS here are my findings

```
SELECT * FROM table1,table2
```

gives the same execution plan and the same records as

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON 1=1
```

and the same thing for

```
SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2
```

Comment: If your first query has no `WHERE` clause, then it would be a `CROSS JOIN`, not an `INNER JOIN`, and have no `ON`.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Though you could write it as `... table1 inner join table2 on 1=1`

Comment: For what I tested on a big data table, the row count is the same with the multiple tables and with an inner join on 1 = 1...

Comment: @MartinSmith - heh, good point

Comment: Additionally, I see that the query plan is the same in both cases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing in SSMS here are my findings

```
SELECT * FROM table1,table2
```

gives the same execution plan and the same records as

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON 1=1
```

and the same thing for

```
SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2
```

Answer (score 1):

the column that defines their relationship.

```
SELECT  *
FROM  table1 
      INNER JOIN table2
           ON table1.ID = table2.ID
```

actually the query you have showed is not `equal`. The first one produces cartesian product of all the records on both table or in other words `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: So, the join will use all the columns from the relations between the 2 tables? Or only from the primary keys?

Comment: the columns that you have defined an index, and these are usually primary and a foreign key. but can also be primary and primary. :D

Comment: So, the first query is a cross join, how should it be rewritten then?

Comment: add `WHERE` clause. like, `WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID`

Comment: hmmm... According to the TSQL reference site (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) it says, under the description of INNER: When no join type is specified, this is the default... Maybe I misread this part?

Comment: @Stécy - That just means that if you don't specify one of `INNER, LEFT, RIGHT, FULL` preceding the `JOIN` keyword then `INNER` is the default. You don't have the `JOIN` keyword in your query.

Comment: it just means that when you try to join the table and you did not specify the type of join, example `SELECT  *
FROM  table1 JOIN table2`, it just mean that you are doing `INNER JOIN`. and is the same as `SELECT  *
FROM  table1 
      INNER JOIN table2`

Comment: Yeah, makes sense now. However, I would like to see the location in the doc where it says that this is a cross join by default (not that I don't believe you, I'm just being thorough) ;)

Comment: @Stécy [not really related to your question but the two are different format standards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334201/why-isnt-sql-ansi-92-standard-better-adopted-over-ansi-89)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1,
    table2
```

is equivalent to:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    table1
CROSS JOIN 
    table2
```

there is no ON statement with a CROSS JOIN.  If you need to filter a CROSS JOIN, put it in the WHERE clause.

```
WHERE table1.DateCreated <= table2.DateModified
```