# SQL JOIN query Optimization with subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, odoo

I used below subquery for get attached records. i need to know is it Optimized query for my task (seems within three month its exists records more than 10,000 ).then is it support for that data load.?

can i use **JOIN** keyword instead of this below method.please advice me to sort this out.
currently i'm using postgresql as my backend.

```
select worker,worktype,paymenttype,sum(output)as totalkgs_ltrs,sum(overkgs)as overkgs_ltrs,sum(workedhrs) as workedhrs,sum(scrap) as scrap,sum(cashworkincome) as cashworkincome,sum(pss) as pss
from (select
  comp.name as company, 
  est.name as estate, 
  div.name as division, 
  wkr.name as worker, 
  txn.date as updateddate, 
  txn.type as worktype, 
  txn.payment_type as paymenttype, 
  txn.names as workedhrs, 
  txn.norm as norm, 
  txn.output as output, 
  txn.over_kgs as overkgs, 
  txn.scrap as scrap, 
  txn.cash_work_income as cashworkincome,
  txn.pss as pss
from 
  bpl_daily_transaction_master txn, 
  res_company comp, 
  bpl_division_n_registration div, 
  bpl_estate_n_registration est, 
  bpl_worker wkr
where 
  comp.id = txn.bpl_company_id and
  div.id  = txn.bpl_division_id and
  est.id  = txn.bpl_estate_id and
  wkr.id  = txn.worker_id
)as subq
group by worker,worktype,paymenttype
```

here shows my result when i execute this query

[image: refer this image]

here is the subquery's code & results tagged at bottom section

```
select
  comp.name as company, 
  est.name as estate, 
  div.name as division, 
  wkr.name as worker, 
  txn.date as updateddate, 
  txn.type as worktype, 
  txn.payment_type as paymenttype, 
  txn.names as workedhrs, 
  txn.norm as norm, 
  txn.output as output, 
  txn.over_kgs as overkgs, 
  txn.scrap as scrap, 
  txn.cash_work_income as cashworkincome,
  txn.pss as pss
from 
  bpl_daily_transaction_master txn, 
  res_company comp, 
  bpl_division_n_registration div, 
  bpl_estate_n_registration est, 
  bpl_worker wkr
where 
  comp.id = txn.bpl_company_id and
  div.id  = txn.bpl_division_id and
  est.id  = txn.bpl_estate_id and
  wkr.id  = txn.worker_id
```

this is above main query result and its shows all records

[image: refer this image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select wkr.name as worker,txn.type as worktype,txn.payment_type as paymenttype,sum(txn.output)as totalkgs_ltrs,sum(txn.over_kgs)as overkgs_ltrs,
       sum(txn.names) as workedhrs,sum(txn.scrap) as scrap,sum(txn.cash_work_income) as cashworkincome,sum(txn.pss) as pss

from 
  bpl_daily_transaction_master txn
inner join res_company comp
   on comp.id = txn.bpl_company_id 
inner join bpl_division_n_registration div
   on div.id  = txn.bpl_division_id
inner join bpl_estate_n_registration est
   on est.id  = txn.bpl_estate_id
inner join bpl_worker wkr
   on wkr.id  = txn.worker_id

group by wkr.name,txn.type,txn.payment_type
```

What you are are doing in your subquery is old ANSI SQL -89 syntax for joining tables which is not recommended.
But as far as performance is concerned I don't think there is difference as confirmed on this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334201/why-isnt-sql-ansi-92-standard-better-adopted-over-ansi-89).

> According to "SQL Performance Tuning" by Peter Gulutzan and Trudy
>   Pelzer, of the six or eight RDBMS brands they tested, there was no
>   difference in optimization or performance of SQL-89 versus SQL-92
>   style joins. One can assume that most RDBMS engines transform the
>   syntax into an internal representation before optimizing or executing
>   the query, so the human-readable syntax makes no difference.