# Sum query results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query where I get a count of some columns my problem is counting all these counts results in a new field

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(u.firstname,' ',u.lastname) AS 'agent',
COUNT(CASE WHEN pa.answer_text LIKE '%yes%' THEN pa.answer_id END) AS yes,
COUNT(CASE WHEN pa.answer_text LIKE '%no%' THEN pa.answer_id END) AS NO,
COUNT(CASE WHEN l2u.lead_status_id IN (4,5,8,39) THEN l2u.lead_id END) AS pending,
COUNT(CASE WHEN l2u.lead_status_id IN (7,14,43) THEN l2u.lead_id END) AS wrong_number,
```

Here is the problem .. what is the correct syntax for this

```
COUNT(pending + wrong_number + yes + NO) AS 'total'
```

```
FROM USER u, poll_votes pv, poll_answers pa, lead_to_user_original l2u

WHERE u.user_id = pv.user_id
AND pv.answer_id = pa.answer_id
AND l2u.lead_id = pv.vote_lead_id
AND (pa.answer_client_one = '869' OR pa.answer_client_two = '869')
AND pv.vote_date BETWEEN '2013-07-01 00:00:01' AND '2013-07-17 23:59:59'
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access aliases in your `SELECT` clause in another field in the select. You can "push" it down to a sub-query, and do something like this:

```
SELECT a.*, pending + wrong_number + yes + no AS 'total'
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(u.firstname,' ',u.lastname) AS 'agent',
        COUNT(CASE WHEN pa.answer_text LIKE '%yes%' THEN pa.answer_id END) AS yes,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN pa.answer_text LIKE '%no%' THEN pa.answer_id END) AS NO,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN l2u.lead_status_id IN (4,5,8,39) THEN l2u.lead_id END) AS pending,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN l2u.lead_status_id IN (7,14,43) THEN l2u.lead_id END) AS wrong_number,
    FROM USER u
    JOIN poll_votes pv
      ON u.user_id = pv.user_id
    JOIN poll_answers pa
      ON pv.answer_id = pa.answer_id
    JOIN lead_to_user_original l2u
      ON l2u.lead_id = pv.vote_lead_id
    WHERE (pa.answer_client_one = '869' OR pa.answer_client_two = '869')
      AND pv.vote_date BETWEEN '2013-07-01 00:00:01' AND '2013-07-17 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY u.user_id
) AS a
```

I also changed your query to use ["ANSI-92 style" joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334201/why-isnt-sql-ansi-92-standard-better-adopted-over-ansi-89), I think it's much more readable...

Answer (score 2):

how about wrapping it in a subquery?

```
SELECT  agent,  yes, no, pending, wrong_number,
        yes + no + pending + wrong_number AS Total
FROM
        (
            SELECT  CONCAT(u.firstname,' ',u.lastname) AS 'agent',
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN pa.answer_text LIKE '%yes%' THEN pa.answer_id END) AS yes,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN pa.answer_text LIKE '%no%' THEN pa.answer_id END) AS NO,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN l2u.lead_status_id IN (4,5,8,39) THEN l2u.lead_id END) AS pending,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN l2u.lead_status_id IN (7,14,43) THEN l2u.lead_id END) AS wrong_number
            FROM    USER u
                    INNER JOIN poll_votes pv 
                        ON u.user_id = pv.user_id 
                    INNER JOIN poll_answers pa 
                        ON pv.answer_id = pa.answer_id
                    INNER JOIN lead_to_user_original l2u 
                        ON l2u.lead_id = pv.vote_lead_id

            WHERE   (pa.answer_client_one = '869' OR pa.answer_client_two = '869')
                    AND pv.vote_date BETWEEN '2013-07-01 00:00:01' AND '2013-07-17 23:59:59'
            GROUP   BY u.user_id
        ) subA
```