# Only taking 1 entry from the other table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 Tables that need to be joined, to illustrate here are my tables:

Table baby

```
    |id|name |action_id|
    |1 |John |1        |
    |2 |Jane |2        |
```

Table action

```
    |id|action|details|
    |1 |laugh |hihihi |
    |1 |laugh |hahaha |
    |2 |cry   |huhuhu |
```

What I have:

```
    |id|name |action_id|action|
    |1 |John |1        |laugh |
    |1 |John |1        |laugh |
    |2 |Jane |3        |cry   |
```

As I didn't need the details, here is what I want:

```
    |id|name |action_id|action|
    |1 |John |1        |laugh |
    |2 |Jane |3        |cry   |
```

Can someone help me make the right query?

Comment: Have you looked at the `DISTINCT` keyword?  Just add it to the beginning of the query you already have.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: write it up @Sablefoste. Stick a fork in this in 2 min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @drew, you can just use the following Query (you might want to confirm the names of your tables don't conflict with the field names):

```
SELECT DISTINCT baby.id, baby.name, action.action 
FROM baby
JOIN action
WHERE baby.action_id=action.id;
```

Comment: Hmmm.... normally I do.  I guess the late hour and the rush to get an answer that works out lead me to this.  An interesting read and opinions about it, however: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334201/why-isnt-sql-ansi-92-standard-better-adopted-over-ansi-89

Comment: I thought my problem lies in the joining clause. Thus, I search only regarding the Join topic. Thanks a lot for the help @Sablefoste !

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ANSI-92 compliant answer to the question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.id, b.name, b.action_id, a.action
FROM baby b INNER JOIN action a ON b.action_id = a.id
```

Comment: I thought my problem lies in the joining clause. Thus, I search only regarding the Join topic. Thanks a lot for the help!