# Subquery returned more than 1 value, syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, inner-join

I am creating my first left join and I am having syntax errors. I been up and down this list and I cannot figure what is the issue. Here is the setup

I have three tables `Mass_List`, `Parent` and `Parent_Place`. They all have the same ID but I need to get the `Date_Close` from `Mass_List` and the `ID` and `Username` from `Parent`, making sure that the user is a paying member, which is know by the column `MBSHIP` in `Parent_Place`.

I do the queries separate and they work but when I do the queries together it tells me my syntax is correct but gives me the following error

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I searched online but nothing close to my case. Any idea what's wrong with my syntax? Here is the query

```
SELECT P.USERNAME, M.DATE_CLOSE, P.ID 
FROM MASS_LIST M, PARENT P
WHERE P.ID =
          (SELECT M.ID 
           FROM MASS_LIST M 
           INNER JOIN PARENT_PLACE PP ON PP.ID = M.ID
           WHERE PP.CLASS_USR = 'PAID' 
             AND M.DATE_CLOSE > getdate() 
             AND PP.MBSHIP > 0)
 AND M.DATE_CLOSE > GETDATE() ORDER BY M.DATE_CLOSE;
```

Comment: Can you post sample data of your tables? the error is clear, your query is returning more than one value and you cant compare a scalar with a vector.

Comment: Don'y mix ansi-92 and pre ansi-92 standards (inner join vs , notation)

Comment: @xQbert I dont know years .. but do you mean this?  Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Yep.  Most engines/compilers can handle one or the other but usually not both in the same query.  In addition it seems that the subselect really isn't needed.  an additional join to parent place should do the trick.  but to know for certain, sample data and expected results would help. and reference for the name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334201/why-isnt-sql-ansi-92-standard-better-adopted-over-ansi-89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need the subslect in the first place...  Just join all 3 tables together...  Though I do find it odd that the "ID" column in each tables is what joins them together.  Seems like your trying to join on the PK of each table which isn't the way they should be joined unless each table is truly a 1-1 relationship with the other... then I'd say interesting table design.

```
SELECT ML.Date_Close, P.ID, P.UserName
FROM mass_List ML
INNER JOIN PARENT P
 on ML.ID = P.ID
INNER JOIN PARENT_PLACE  PP
 on P.ID = PP.ID
WHERE PP.MBSHIP > 0
  and PP.Class_user = 'PAID'
  and M.Date_Close > getDate()
order by m.date_Close
```

Comment: Thank you @xQbert that did it. Appreciate it!