# How to understand the SQL SYNTAN which join a table to itself without using INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

There is a TABLE name is `team`, total 1 column '*name*' with 4 records (`'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'`) representing four football teams.

**Requires**: Using one SQL syntax to show all the possible combinations of tow team.

I just learned about `self_join` so i used this:

```
SELECT a.name, b.name
FROM team AS a
INNER JOIN team AS b
WHERE a.name < b.name;
```

**The question is**:
I saw the SQL SYNTAX which works out pretty good, but i can't figure out how it works.
Anyone could help? thx.

This **SQL SYNTAX** is below:

```
SELECT a.name, b.name
from team a, team b 
where a.name < b.name;
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM A, B ... WHERE <bla>` is *synonym* for `SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON (<bla>)` ;)

Comment: You saw archaic SQL syntax -- as if you were reading Shakespeare and started to talk like his characters because you saw the words written down.  Joins are correctly written using standard, explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax, not with commas in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These queries are just different ways to write the same thing.  [The first is ANSI-89 join syntax, the second ANSI-92 join syntax.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/334201/50552)  The newer syntax is preferred because it keeps join conditions closer to the joined table, especially for multiple joins.

Comment: Thx. I'd better with New set operations  UNION JOIN.