# INNER JOIN not working for the first table in a multi table select statement

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to select data from same table twice and it works but it is not allowing me to use the first table in the list in `INNER JOIN`, if I use the second table from the list in the join it works

So this is the query that works fine

```
SELECT 
    TOP 1 
    RIT_First.LastModified, 
    RIT_Last.LastModified
FROM 
    dbo.ItemTransaction RIT_First, 
    dbo.ItemTransaction RIT_Last
JOIN dbo.Item RI ON RIT_Last.ItemId = RI.Id -- Using the second table in the join
```

But when I do this

```
SELECT 
    TOP 1 
    RIT_First.LastModified, 
    RIT_Last.LastModified
FROM 
    dbo.ItemTransaction RIT_First, 
    dbo.ItemTransaction RIT_Last
JOIN dbo.Item RI ON RIT_First.ItemId = RI.Id -- Using the first table in the join
```

I start getting this error

> The multi-part identifier "RIT_First.ItemId" could not be bound.

So is it like we can use only last table in the list of tables in the join or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Why are you mix and matching ANSI-92 and ANSI-89 JOINs here?

Comment: Checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334201/why-isnt-sql-ansi-92-standard-better-adopted-over-ansi-89

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is your mix and matching of ANSI-89 JOINs and ANSI-92 JOINs. Just *don't* use ANSI-89 JOINs any more; they were superseded *30* years ago.

If you use ANSI-92 JOINs the whole way through, you don't have a problem:

```sql
SELECT TOP (1)
       RIT_First.LastModified,
       RIT_Last.LastModified
FROM dbo.ItemTransaction RIT_First
     CROSS JOIN dbo.ItemTransaction RIT_Last
     JOIN dbo.Item RI ON RIT_First.ItemId = RI.Id
ORDER BY {Expression(s)};
```

If, for some bizarre reason, you are compelled to use an ANSI-89 JOIN, then you would need to put the join criteria in the `WHERE`:

```sql
SELECT TOP (1)
       RIT_First.LastModified,
       RIT_Last.LastModified
FROM dbo.ItemTransaction RIT_First,
     dbo.ItemTransaction RIT_Last,
     dbo.Item RI 
WHERE RIT_First.ItemId = RI.Id
ORDER BY {Expression(s)};
```

But, like I said, just *don't* do that. See this article by Aaron Bertrand for more information: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)